# Rails override activerecord model getter to necessitate easier querying of associations to that model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to override ActiveRecord model getters so that they return a relations fields? For example, I am currently trying to sort a :meetings table that has a belongs_to relations ship based on the :user it belongs to. If I want to sort by :users.first_name, I am having to pass some sort of identifier in with the params to let the back know it needs to instead sort by the :users table. The solution I have works, but it necessitates hard-coding some combinations in the controller that is not very DRY, and is a little too specific for my liking. Just trying to think of an optimization for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using ActiveRecord's [scope](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

```
class Meeting
  belongs_to :user

  scope :sorted_by_users_first_name, -> { joins(:user).order('user.first_name')) }
end
```

Then doing `Meeting.sorted_by_users_first_name` should return the meetings sorted by their user's first_name in ascending order.

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing. I've really not done anything with scopes before, they're really quite handy!